# Refresh listView populated from JSON response every 2 seconds

Tags: java, android, json, listview, fragment

I am working on an android app in which an fragment has a listview that is populated by JSON response from a PHP server. The list view displays as needed and currently updates whenever the fragment is being viewed. However, this is also a problem as the list only updates if the view is changed and I wanted the listView to clear and update every few milli seconds.

My fragment code is:

```
public class eventFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

ListView eventView;
ArrayList<Events> eventList;
EventListAdapter adapter;
String streamName;
String applicationType = "live";
private static String value;

String url = "http://192.168.43.149/testing/eventStream.php";

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public eventFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment eventFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static eventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    eventFragment fragment = new eventFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);
    eventView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    eventList = new ArrayList<Events>();
    JSONObject streamInfo = new JSONObject();
    try {
        streamInfo.put("applicationType", applicationType);

        postJSONObject(url,streamInfo);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}


public void postJSONObject(final String myurl, final JSONObject parameters) {

    class postJSONObject extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //dialog[0] = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //dialog[0].setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            //dialog[0].setTitle("Connecting server");
            //dialog[0].show();
            //dialog[0].setCancelable(false);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadIntoEventView(s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                StringBuffer response = null;
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(parameters.toString());
                writer.close();
                out.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("responseCode" + responseCode);
                switch (responseCode) {
                    case 200:
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        response = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(inputLine);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        return response.toString();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

    postJSONObject postJSONObject = new postJSONObject();
    postJSONObject.execute();
}

private void loadIntoEventView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    eventList.clear();
    final String[]  events = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        events[i] = obj.getString("title");

        Events video = new Events();

        video.setTitle(events[i]);
        //vidoe.setDescription(obj.getString("channelDescriptipn"));
        //channel.setDateCreated(obj.get("createdOn"));
        //vidoe.setImage(obj.getString("logoLocation"));

        eventList.add(video);
    }
    //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.eventparsedata, eventList);
    eventView.setAdapter(adapter);



    eventView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            streamName = Arrays.asList(events).get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StreamPlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("videoname", streamName);
            startActivity(intent);

            System.out.println("arr: " + Arrays.asList(events).get(position));


        }


    });


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do any action every x seconds you can use this code (in this example, x is 1000 milliseconds = 1 second)

define this in your fragment class:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable updatePage = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // do what you want in here (calling your web service request)                    


                    handler.postDelayed(updatePage,1000);
                }
            };
```

and use it like this (put it in onCreateView method):

```
handler.postDelayed(updatePage,1000);
```